# Images in React-bootstrap Carousel Not Showing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I'm having a problem showing images in the React-bootstrap carousel. The carousel itself works. I see the arrows and index at the bottom. But the images just won't show. When I inspect element and hover over the image component, it works fine. The image has been linked fine, the carousel is working, but the images wont show. Anyone knows a fix on this problem?
This is what my test code looks like. I just put it in the about me section for reference. See image for working carousel and working image in dev tools.

```
import React from "react";
import "./section.css";
import "../../App.css";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import { Carousel } from "react-bootstrap";

function About() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <section class="about section">
      <Carousel>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            class="d-block w-100"
            src={require("../../assets/keukenhofplattegrond.png")}
            alt="First slide"
          ></img>
        </Carousel.Item>
        <Carousel.Item>
          <img
            class="d-block w-100"
            src="https://lorempixel.com/800/400/food/1"
            alt="First slide"
          ></img>
        </Carousel.Item>
      </Carousel>
    </section>
  );
}

export default About;
```

[dev tools inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGL86.png)

[Carousel image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y4ZF.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `class` to `className`. `class` keyword is reserved in Javascript and that is why React uses `className` instead.

More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#specifying-attributes-with-jsx

Comment: I changed it but nothing happened unfortunately

Comment: Can you check if the sources of the images are loaded correctly?

Comment: Yup I did, I even imported it as an object and used it as a standalone img(outside of the carousel) and it showed perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Please try adding width and height to the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try to import the img and then pass it to the img tag.

import {yourImage} from "route" and then put it on the src.

maybe that works.

Comment: Sadly, doesn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: Thanks mate, this worked for me.

Additionally, I also had to move the images folder into the same folder where I had my js file containing Carousel.